# How to resovle dependencies names between Debian and Buildroot?

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, dependencies, debian, buildroot

We have a running app with nodejs and [@abandonware/noble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abandonware/noble#common-problems) package on Radxa Zero with DietPi OS (Debian) which controls a bluetooth device. The documentation of the package says you need `sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez libbluetooth-dev libudev-dev`. These are Debian packages. **What is the equivalent name of these in buildroot**?. How can I make sure these Debian packages are installed in my Buildroot image. So far I checked everything for `bluez-tools`, `bluez-utils` in `Target packages` for my image. I can scan and find my BLE device with `bluetoothctl` and `hcitool lescan`. When executing on my image the application fails with a similar failure when dependencies are missing.

```
# NOBLE_HCI_DEVICE_ID=1 node .

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: File not found
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/client/node_modules/@abandonware/bluetooth-hci-socket/lib/native.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Currently running node 14.20.1.

Strange output of `bluemoon`. Is this relevant?

```
# bluemoon 
Bluemoon configuration utility ver 5.65
Failed to open HCI user channel
```

Answer (score 0):

I think https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/bluez5_utils-headers/bluez5_utils-headers.mk is the package that contains the needed headers that you need when including libbluetooth headers that are needed to build native modules.

In any case, I can recommend https://github.com/Emill/node-ble-host instead of noble. This package implements more features and is supposed to be much more stable and bug-free; it's also not "abandoned"... (I am the author of this package).